# UTC time to GPS time converter by Python

Tags: python, gps, utc

I have a UTC time (epoch Unix time) formatted as timestamp as below.
`1496224620`
(Human readable value: May 31, 2017 09:57:00)

I need to convert the timestamp formatted as Unix time into GPS time format as below.
`1180259838`
(Human readable value: May 31, 2017 09:57:00)

I need a python program (algorithm is fine for me) to convert timestamp formatted as Unix time to timestamp formatted as GPS time.

There is one PHP program to do so. I can change from PHP code to Python code to have a Python program by myself. But I think there is also a short way (built-in function of Python) that can implement my expectation more effective.
Here is the link of PHP program
https://www.andrews.edu/~tzs/timeconv/timealgorithm.html

Comment: The code linked to by the OP contains a static list of leap seconds. I don't know if the list accounts for the leap second at the end of 2016. In any case, the code will become obsolete after the next leap second. Any solution will have to have a means of accessing an up-to-date list of all leap seconds since the inception of GPS.

Comment: @Gerard Ashton: The list has leap second at the end of 2016 (`1167264017`). By your comment, I am thinking about 1 problem: If the next leap second is unpredictable, how can we know when it will occur? And we must update our source code manually for each time the leap second occurs (ex. next 2018, 2019,...)? Is there any feasible way to prevent this problem?

Comment: The only way I know is to download a list in a predictable format, such as https://www.ietf.org/timezones/data/leap-seconds.list and parse it. You could use the fact that the official standard https://www.itu.int/rec/R-REC-TF.460-6-200202-I/en only allows them at the end of a month, so you could keep track of the last time you checked and only check if it's been a month since your last check. Announcements are about 6 months before the next leap. If you want to convert a date far in the future, tough, you can't.

Comment: @Gerard Ashton: Thank you. I downloaded your given list. It is the newest list with leap seconds at 1 Jan 2017. By your answer "If you want to convert a date far in the future, tough, you can't.", I can be clear to know there is no way to know leap seconds in far future (ex. next 2 years). In the below answer of slash-dev, we must rely on some devices to know the leap seconds in the future (ex. ublox). So, if there is no such devices, we can not know the leap seconds in future. Anyway, thanks so much for your answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just subtract 315964782 from the UNIX time.

GPS Time starts on January 5, 1980.  UNIX time starts on January 1, 1970.  They simply have different starting points, or [Epochs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_(reference_date)#Notable_epoch_dates_in_computing).  The difference between those two Epochs is the number of seconds between those two dates **PLUS** 18 GPS leap seconds (so far).

As others have noted, [GPS leap seconds](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_Positioning_System#Leap_seconds) are periodically added as the Earth's rotation gradually slows.

> we must update our source code manually for each time the leap second occurs (ex. next 2018, 2019,...)? Is there any feasible way to prevent this problem?

Many devices have a message that indicates the "current" number of GPS seconds in effect.  My C++ [NeoGPS](https://github.com/SlashDevin/NeoGPS) library has an [example program](https://github.com/SlashDevin/NeoGPS/blob/master/examples/ublox/ublox.ino#L142) that requests the current number of GPS seconds from a ublox device (binary message defined [here](https://github.com/SlashDevin/NeoGPS/blob/master/src/ublox/ubxmsg.h#L353)).  See ublox NEO-xx specifications for more information regarding the NAV-TIMEGPS message.

Other manufacturers may have their own protocols and messages for obtaining the current GPS leap seconds.

#### HOWEVER:

Most GPS devices report times in UTC, with the leap seconds already included.  Unless you are using a GPS time based on the start of the week (midnight Sunday), you should not need to know the GPS leap seconds.

If you are trying to convert from a "GPS time since start of week", then you would also need to know the current [GPS week number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_Positioning_System#Format) to convert "GPS time of week" to UTC.

ublox devices report some fix information with a timestamp that is "GPS milliseconds since start of week."  [This NeoGPS file](https://github.com/SlashDevin/NeoGPS/blob/master/src/GPSTime.h) shows several methods for converting between "GPS milliseconds since start of week" and UTC.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. "Just subtract `315964782` from the UNIX time" is a correct answer and I know that `315964782` is valid at now (June 2017). It may be obsolete at the Dec 31st, 2017 and next years. As your explanation, I understand that we must use some devices to indicate leap seconds if we want to know leap seconds in the future (your example is ublox device). If there is no such devices, we can not indicate leap seconds by a "stand-alone" python program. "stand-alone" means just a python program without any GPS devices.

Comment: I do not understand well about your explanation in [b]HOWEVER[\b], "GPS time based on the start of week". I am just investigate about GPS time and Unix time, but I can understand a basic knowledge through your answer: we must use a GPS devices to get the leap seconds in the far future.

Comment: If you use a GPS device to get the GPS leap seconds, you should be aware that the GPS device can also provide the current UTC time.  It converts GPS time into UTC time for you.  But there is no way to get the GPS leap seconds in a stand-alone system.  The **International Earth Rotation Service** announces leap seconds as they are needed.

Comment: Package glue :: Module gpstime  http://software.ligo.org/docs/glue/glue.gpstime-module.html

Comment: Isn't that January 6, 1980 instead? ("The original origin of this counter was midnight 5 January–6 January 1980." in [a wikipedia-referenced doc](https://tf.nist.gov/general/pdf/1602.pdf))

Answer (score -2):

How about:

```
import datetime
datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(int("1284101485")).strftime('%B-%Y-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

Comment: It can not solve my question. I need convert from `1496224620` to `1180259838` (from Unix timestamp to GPS timestamp).